# Query: In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm mixing 2 sheets (input1 and input2) into a 3rd sheet using a Google Sheets Query.
The only thing is that I need some columns and not all of them, and in a different order.

sheet: **input1**

```
date    serie_1 serie_2 client
1/1/2019    2   6   Client A
1/2/2019    1   6   Client A
1/3/2019    5   8   Client B
1/4/2019    3   8   Client A
1/5/2019    8   2   Client B
1/6/2019    7   5   Client A
1/7/2019    5   5   Client B
1/8/2019    6   6   Client A
1/9/2019    4   3   Client B
1/10/2019   4   10  Client A
1/11/2019   5   8   Client B
1/12/2019   5   8   Client A
1/13/2019   2   5   Client B
1/14/2019   9   8   Client A
1/15/2019   4   1   Client B
```

sheet **input2**

```
date    serie_3 serie_4 client
1/1/2019    6   1   Client A
1/2/2019    6   1   Client A
1/3/2019    8   1   Client A
1/4/2019    8   1   Client A
1/5/2019    2   1   Client A
1/6/2019    5   1   Client A
1/7/2019    5   1   Client B
1/8/2019    6   1   Client B
1/9/2019    3   1   Client A
1/10/2019   10  1   Client A
1/11/2019   8   1   Client B
1/12/2019   8   1   Client B
1/13/2019   5   1   Client A
1/14/2019   8   1   Client B
1/15/2019   1   1   Client A
```

expected **output** using Query

```
date    serie_1 serie_2 serie_3 client
```

The following query is processed:

```
={query({input1!A2:D},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,' ',Col4 where Col1 is not null label ' '''");query({input2!A2:D},"select Col1,' ','  ','   ',Col2,Col4 where Col1 is not null label ' ''','  ''','   '''")}
```

**Results**

```
Error
In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: here is the link to the sheets, in case of: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15GyoGiOs-X4zqnNqThHAeCTKtcpR9IqULFesVQly58Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: in 1st query you selected 5 columns but in 2nd query you selected 6 columns - therfore that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
={query({input1!A2:D},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,' ',Col4 where Col1 is not null label ' '''");
  query({input2!A2:D},"select Col1,' ','  ',Col2,Col4 where Col1 is not null label ' ''','  '''")}
```